# AS being ignored in a subquery

Tags: sql, database

Still learning SQL here... I have part of a subquery:

```
(Select MAX(cost) AS Cost_of_Car FROM Car_Purchase)
```

But it does not take my label just uses the one from the table, in this case "cost"

Any ideas?

**EDIT: Just realized I could in my SELECT statement call out AS "NAME OF COLUMN", but why does it not accept AS in the subquery?**

**POSTING FULL QUERY**

```
SELECT CAR.name, Car_Purchase.cost_per_night, Car_Purchase.description
FROM Car_Purchase
JOIN CAR ON Car_Purchase.purchase_id = CAR.purchase_id
GROUP BY CAR.name, Car_Purchase.cost_per_night, Car_Purchase.description
HAVING Car_Purchase.cost = (SELECT MAX(cost) AS Cost_of_Car FROM Car_Purchase)
```

Comment: You may need to elaborate -- it's working for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58e4a/1

Comment: Can you post your full query? looks like the problem is not in the subquery

Comment: @IswantoSan Full query posted above

Comment: @JMeterX: In your full query, what is the purpose aliasing the subquery result? It's only used in `where` clause..`Where` clause is used for filter the data, not to display the data..

Comment: In your edits, the column alias isn't used at all. Why do you think it's being ignored?

Comment: @sgeddes I thought `AS Cost_of_Car` should change the display name of the output for `Car_Purchase.cost` from the table `Car_Purchase`.  Otherwise the column will just say "cost." Just starting out with this so I am wondering if my logic is wrong to even include `AS` there or if I have logic wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AS` keyword is not being ignored.
You're using subquery in `where` clause. Remember, `where` clause is used for filtering the query result, not for displaying the data.

If you want to see how `AS` work in subquery, try this:

```
SELECT CAR.name, Car_Purchase.cost_per_night, Car_Purchase.description, Cost_of_Car
FROM Car_Purchase 
JOIN CAR ON Car_Purchase.purchase_id = CAR.purchase_id
join (SELECT MAX(cost) AS Cost_of_Car FROM Car_Purchase) subquery
ON Car_Purchase.cost = subquery.Cost_of_Car
GROUP BY CAR.name, Car_Purchase.cost_per_night, Car_Purchase.description
```

In this query, I put the subquery in `from` clause. So your query result now have `Cost_of_Car` column and you can display it in `select` clause.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, since, as noted by others the Max(Cost) is not being used elsewhere in the query, you don't need to alias it at all.  And since you don't have a aggregate function anywhere in the sql it does not need to be a group By query

```
Select cp.name, cp.Cost CostOfCar, 
     cp.cost_per_night, cp.description
From Car_Purchase cp Join Car c 
     On c.purchase_id = cp.purchase_id
Where cp.cost = (SELECT MAX(cost) FROM Car_Purchase)
```

Is sufficient and should work